# cumulative distribution

Tags: probability

If the cumulative distribution function of is given by the function below, what is 
$P (X < 0.80)$.

$$\begin{cases}f(x)=0 & \text{if } x \leq 0  \\
f(x)=x^2& \text{if } 0 <  x \leq 1  \\
f(x)=1& \text{if }  x > 1\end{cases}$$

My answer is:
$P (X < 0.80) = (0.80)^2$

Is my answer correct?   Thanks.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, since $f$ is the cumulative distribution, it is defined as $f(x)=P(X<x)$, so $P(X<0.8)=f(0.8)=0.64$